# Replace single quotes without changing the apostrophe

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a data frame with column Title, I want to replace the single quotes to double quotes without changing the apostrophe. For example, 'I don't go to work tomorrow' . It should be "I don't go to work tomorrow".

I tried like this:

```
gsub("(\\w'\\w+) |, ", "\\1", "I don't go to work tomorrow")
```

I have tried a couple of ways, but have not got the result as expected.
I try `str_replace_all()` in `stringr`, but it replaces all ' into ". Every recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: This works but not sure how you want to generalise: `gsub("go to\\s","",gsub("^'|'$","","'I don't go to work tomorrow'"))`.(would be nice to see how this can be done in a single RegEx).

Comment: @NelsonGon I have just fixed my question. I want to replace 'I don't go to work tomorrow' ==> "I don't go to work tomorrow". I want to replace the single to double quotation marks without changing apostrophe.

Comment: Maybe `str_replace_all("'I don't go to work tomorrow'", "^'|'$", '"')`?

Comment: @Phil you did it so easy, but I have spent hours to find. Big thumb

Comment: Regex is really hard and something I've been struggling with too, it's normal to run into these kinds of walls.

Answer (score 2):

I think your rule is perhaps as simple as: if an apostrophe has something (non-space) before *and* after it, then don't replace it; otherwise, replace it.

```r
gsub("^'|(?<= )'|'(?= )|'$", '"', "'I don't go to work tomorrow'", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "\"I don't go to work tomorrow\""
```

(Updated so that it does not consume the preceding/following space, if present.)

Comment: perfect!. That is what I am trying to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: This rule would fail in the case of possessive plurals (if any exist in OP's data).

Comment: @H1 good point ... and now we get into a bit more NLP, as I *know* that that is in English but do not know if any other languages have similar corner-cases. I don't know how to properly catch a possessive plural without false-negatives ...)

Answer (score 2):

**Patterns**

To match an apostrophe only at the start/end of the string:

```
^'|'$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXYH89/1)

If the apostophe is searched only outside a *word*, you may use

```
\b'\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXYH89/4). Here, the `'` is matched only if it is not enclosed on both ends with letters, digits or underscores since all `'` that are enclosed with word chars are skipped/failed.

If you need to match a `'` only when it is not between two letters, use

```
'(?!(?<=[A-Za-z]')[A-Za-z])    # ASCII only
'(?!(?<=\p{L}')\p{L})          # Any Unicode letters
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXYH89/3).

**Usage**

```
gsub("^'|'$", '"', "'I don't go to work tomorrow 2'5.'")
## => "I don't go to work tomorrow 2'5." 
gsub("\\b'\\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'", '"', "'I don't go to work tomorrow 2'5.'", perl=TRUE)
## => "I don't go to work tomorrow 2'5."
gsub("'(?!(?<=\\p{L}')\\p{L})", '"', "'I don't go to work tomorrow 2'5.'", perl=TRUE)
## => "I don't go to work tomorrow 2"5."
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/TPBD74174).

Comment: Nice patterns, something to remember :)

Comment: It is really nice!